# Missing e-mail notification for Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, notification, 20.04, mail-notification

I am using Thunderbird (version 68.7) on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 but I do not get any notification popup in the system tray.

I switched on notifications in the Thunderbird settings and notifications from other applications (such as Ubuntu Software Updater) are visible.

Besides, I used the same Thunderbird configuration on Ubuntu 19.04 earlier (as kept the config files and stored messages on my home partition)

Do I need to install any additional packages?

Comment: Just to make sure, is Thunderbird still running? Or you clicked the X button?

Comment: @pomsky It is running. I rebooted several times, and messages arrive in Thunderbird, but I only see them when I open the window.

Comment: I filed a bug report on this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634853

Comment: thunderbird v91 => settings => incoming e-mail-messages

Answer (score 0):

thunderbird v91 => settings => incoming e-mail-messages